# Does SIMPER in Vegan show percentage dissimilarities or similarities and is there a way to show both?

Tags: vegan

The summary function for simper in vegan provides an output that looks like this for my data:

```
summary(with(env, simper(species, env$Habitat)))

Contrast: Fringe_Mudflat 
                           average       sd  ratio     ava     avb cumsum
Bairdiella ronchus        0.255035 0.142025 1.7957 48.3333 50.6667 0.4708
Diapterus rhombeus        0.054406 0.086815 0.6267  6.1667  1.8333 0.5712
Stellifer colonensis      0.048659 0.086382 0.5633  5.5000  3.5000 0.6611
Sphoeroides testudineus   0.038510 0.041463 0.9288  0.0000  5.3333 0.7322
Anchovia clupeoides       0.026492 0.026885 0.9854  1.5000  3.6667 0.7811
```

and from what Ive read it seems these percentages (average and cumsum) are showing the percentage contribution to the dissimilarity between groups. However the first species clearly has very close means in each group (ava and avb), it really therefore looks like it is picking up this species because of its similarity between groups rather than dissimilarity. Does anyone know if this is definitely dissimilarity or similarity or a mix?

Why is the 'average' so different from the first 'cumsum' and which one should be presented in a paper?

Is there a way to display both percentages for dissimilarity and similarity. I see people presenting this in papers and I assume they get it from Primer but I would like to do it in R.

Comment: Does the documentation help? You can read it with `?simper`. It may be enlightening to also read the chapter starting "The results of ‘simper’ can be very difficult to interpret."

Comment: @JariOksanen No I find it quite contradictory. Firstly it's called SIMPER for 'similarity percentage' but then states 'The contribution of individual species to the overall Bray-Curtis dissimilarity'. The results I have displayed above make it unclear whether these percentages are similarity or dissimilarity. Also the SIMPER function doesn't seem to provide a method of returning both similarity and dissimilarity results. I have read Warton 2012,  but these are surely fundamental questions that should be clear but I can't seem to find the answers. Is there a better test than SIMPER?

Comment: The definition is similar as in the original paper (Clarke 1993, p. 127, see ref in `?simper`). The method is defined for dissimilarities as you see when you read the original paper. The relationship between similarity _s_ and dissimilarity _d_ is _s_ = 1-_d_. Please read again the part in documentation which explains the problems with variable species contributing to the measure.

Comment: Thankyou @JariOksanen I had suspected that the dissimilarity/similarity were simply related in that way

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know if this is definitely dissimilarity or similarity or a mix?

'vegan::simper()' is defined as the proportion each species contributes to the Bray-Curtis distance as described in the original paper.

> Why is the 'average' so different from the first 'cumsum' and which one should be presented in a paper?

The documentation is not clear here. cumsum is given in % of overall distance, as reported in the original paper.

Note that simper

> very badly confounds the mean between group differences and within group variation

which might be the case with your dataset.